# Bash While loop new arguments

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Hi can someone please help me with an infinite loop that is to take new arguments.
Is there a read command that each space as a new argument like the command line does. all seem to set it all to one big argument

I have a script, when called it enters an infinite loop.
The first argument will determine a case to call another script, the second argument will then be sent to that script.
I then want to loop around again and ask the user for two arguments again in the same line. The first determining the case and using the second...

However I want these to be in the one line as if it was the command line.
I believe the read command will set the whole line to a variable while i want to do $1 and $2 again.

I provided a little code to describe my issue, thank you in advance

I basically need a read command that will split into arguments like the command line.

```
while true :
do

        # make decision using case..in..esac 
        choice = $1
        case $choice in
                create)

                        ./create.sh $2
                        ;;
                add)
                        ./add.sh $2     

                        ;;
                    *)
                        echo "Error: Invalid option..." 
                        ;;
        esac
done
```

Comment: Please check your code at shellcheck.net first.

Comment: Updated code, removing warnings from shellcheck.net

Comment: @AshutoshJindal So you changed the code in this question, making it behave differently from what OP actually uses?

Comment: _"I believe the read command will set the whole line to a variable while i want to do $1 and $2 again."_  Try `read one two`.

Comment: Kakawak, changes made by my edit removed [these](http://i.imgur.com/am2zvFc.png) warnings. Check if you are happy with these please? If not, revert my edit.

Answer (score 2):

You want to "ask the user for two arguments."  There are at least three ways, listed below.  I think you want to put any of these after the `do` and before the `case`.

1. Like @John1024 said,

   ```
   read choice second_arg
   ```

   will fill in `$choice` and `$second_arg`.  **Edit** use `choice` directly and you won't need `choice="$1"`.
2. This sequence:

   ```
   read
   set -- $REPLY
   ```

   will replace `$1`, `$2`, ... with the words from the command line.  Then you can still use `choice="$1"` like you have it.
3. To keep the command line parameters and be more general,

   ```
   read -a inputs
   ```

   will read the words into the array `inputs`, so you can reference them as `${inputs[0]}`, `${inputs[1]}`, ... for however many inputs there are.  Then you can use

   ```
   choice="${inputs[0]}"
   ```

   rather than `choice="$1"`.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.

```
while true :
do
    echo -n "Enter Your Choice  > "
    read text

    arg1=$(echo "$text" | awk '{print $1}')
    arg2=$(echo "$text" | awk '{print $2}')
    # make decision using case..in..esac 
    choice="$arg1"
    case $choice in
            create)

                    ./create.sh $arg2
                    ;;
            add)
                    ./add.sh $arg2    
                    ;;
                *)
                    echo "Error: Invalid option..." 
                    ;;
    esac
done
```